# How would I make MongoDB return documents in the order they were inserted?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB's db.collection.find().limit(10000) does NOT return the first 10000 documents I inserted. How would I make MongoDB return documents in the order they were inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort items by _id field.

id field is auto-increment and you can sort item in asc or desc to get last or first of you collection.

```query
// sort desc
db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(10000) 
// sort asc
db.collection.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(10000)
```

Comment: But sorting is done after find() returns the results (db.collection.find().sort()), and If there are tens of millions of documents stored in the database, it's NOT sufficient to sort anything at all. Plus what if multiple sources are writing to the database at the same time? we just wanna retrieve 10000 documents  per find() query without sorting.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. You can't call `.find()` on the `db`, you need `db.collection.find()`. Also, the second parameter in the `find()` method is a projection document so `{_id:-1}` isn't valid. Only `{_id: 0}` or `{_id:1}` are valid and anyway, this doesn't result in any sorting order, it's purely to ommit or include the field in the output.

Comment: @AskrAskr Actually, the `.sort()` and `.limit()` methods modify the query prior to sending it to the server, so both the sort and limit are processed server-side.  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/find/#specify-a-sort-and-limit

Comment: The _id field is not actually generated by the server during insert, it is generated by the driver before sending the documents.  This means that if you have multiple machines doing inserts, sorting by the _id will arrange them by machine within each second.  This is not strictly insertion order, but may be close enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb sorts document based on a [natual order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-natural-order). However, as you have found out, it is not 100% reliable. Documents grow and move internally.

Since you have 10s of millions of rows you face the problem of having to use `.find()` which will select all documents, then sort them, then limit to 10000. Not great for performance, I agree.

Mongodb has a [$natural](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) operator that you can use to sort results in their natural order (on disk) but best practice is to [create a view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/create-view/) and use it that way.

You could try this and check for performance:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$ne : null}}).sort({ $natural: 1 }).limit(10000);
```

Note the use of `{_id: {$ne : null}}`. This forces `$natural` to use indexes to fulfil the query (speed things up).

> Queries that include a sort by $natural order do not use indexes to fulfill the query predicate with the following exception: If the query predicate is an equality condition on the _id field { _id:  }, then the query with the sort by $natural order can use the _id index.

Disclaimer:

> The $natural parameter returns items according to their natural order within the database. This ordering is an internal implementation feature, and you should not rely on any particular ordering of the documents.

However, I would think sorting by `_id` would result in better insertion ordering. That's becuase if your `_id` field is an `ObjectId` then:

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
> a 2-byte process id, and
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

So the 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch will always be incremental. Try this way:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(10000);
```

You could then do this to get the next 10000:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(20000).skip(10000);
```